# Which is the best way to escape the string when using split method in Java?

Tags: java, java-8, split

I try to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`, but I find it can escape `$` but do not escape `|`. So I try to use the other method `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`, but it do not escape `{`. So I can only write a method like this. Does any java class already have this method?

```
String sampleStr="$abc.|{@#$abc";
String splitStr="{@#$"; 
System.out.println(Matcher.quoteReplacement(splitStr));
System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(splitStr));
System.out.println(splitStr.replace("\\", "\\\\")
         .replace("*", "\\*")
         .replace("+", "\\+").replace("|", "\\|")
         .replace("{", "\\{").replace("}", "\\}")
         .replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)")
         .replace("^", "\\^").replace("$", "\\$")
         .replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]")
         .replace("?", "\\?").replace(",", "\\,")
         .replace(".", "\\.").replace("&", "\\&")); 

/* have exception when the split String contains "{"}
System.out.println(sampleStr.split(Matcher.quoteReplacement(splitStr)).length);
System.out.println(sampleStr.split(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(splitStr)).length);*/
System.out.println(sampleStr.split(splitStr.replace("\\", "\\\\")
         .replace("*", "\\*")
         .replace("+", "\\+").replace("|", "\\|")
         .replace("{", "\\{").replace("}", "\\}")
         .replace("(", "\\(").replace(")", "\\)")
         .replace("^", "\\^").replace("$", "\\$")
         .replace("[", "\\[").replace("]", "\\]")
         .replace("?", "\\?").replace(",", "\\,")
         .replace(".", "\\.").replace("&", "\\&")).length);
```

Comment: What is the expected output based on input `$abc.|{@#$abc` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split String without regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038102/how-to-split-string-without-regex)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen,sampleStr.split(splitStr).length should be 2

Comment: @flower (by the way, it's not recommended to only mention the question in the title. Better to repeat it in the question body)

Comment: @flower Your comment doesn't answer the question, which is about what your output should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) is, as the name suggests, for quoting a *replacement* string. When you want to quote a pattern string, you have to use [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

```java
String sampleStr="$abc.|{@#$abc";
String splitStr="{@#$";
for(String s: sampleStr.split(Pattern.quote(splitStr)))
    System.out.println(s);
```

```
$abc.|
abc
```

Note that instead of converting a string to a quoted string, to let the regex engine convert it back to the literal string when parsing, you can tell the engine directly that you want to perform a literal match:

```java
for(String s: Pattern.compile(splitStr, Pattern.LITERAL).split(sampleStr))
    System.out.println(s);
```

It’s a bit more to write but more efficient. Further, it works with arbitrary `CharSequence` inputs, not only with `String`.